# Black/cracked screen

Tags: icloud, iphone, screen

Last month I dropped my iphone4 and cracked the front screen really bad, but still worked. About a week ago I dropped it again and cracked the backing, again, still worked perfectly fine, but the other day I was talking on the phone and after I hung up it randomly went black screen and would not light up yet it still rings when someone calls. Therefore it still works but the screen does not. I Just need to know if there is a way that I can access my phone (pictures ect..) out side of icloud? Being a dummy I did not use icloud. ever.

By the way, I only have a PC so, phoneview will not work for me(so I think).

Answer (score 1):

Try an app called iFunBox, I believe there is a windows version. It should be able to assist you with recovering your information.